# Auto Refresh em aplicação Xamarin.forms de tempo em tempo

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que na tela principal terá alguns botões, e estes botões acessam uma URL mandando comandos de ligado e desligado tudo isto através do HttpClient e persistindo todas estas informações.

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

- Tenho 3 botões todos com status desligado.
- Usuário 1 com o seu celular clica no botão 3 que acessa o servidor
  e persiste esta informação para ligado
- O Usuário 2 com celular deve de tempo em tempo saber o status destes botões
- Ambos os Usuários poderão utilizar os recurso de ligar e desligar os botões.

Como fazer a activity de tempo em tempo realizar esta atualização, tentei fazer o exemplo abaixo mas obtive sucesso.

Fico no aguardo.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

private void doTheAutoRefresh()
        {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // Write code for your refresh logic
            doTheAutoRefresh();
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigos solucionei o problema e para melhor detalhar e compartilhar o que consegui fazer, tive que responder minha própria pergunta e não somente comentar

Importei a biblioteca:
**using Android.OS;**

Inicializei Handler:
**Handler handler = new Handler();**

Tenho uma função que inicializa os botões que estão na tela:

```
InicializaButtons()
{
    //Realiza os procedimentos de inicialização dos botões

    //Esta função não só inicializa, mas é usada varias vezes no decorrer da utilização do software, quando necessário.


    //Aqui esta a mágica do negócio
    //De 5 em 5 segundos estou chamando a função InicializaButtons
    handler.PostDelayed(InicializaButtons, 5000);
}
```

Espero ajudar muitas pessoas com esta solução.

Estou testando aqui para ver o rendimento do dispositivo, a já visto estamos mexendo com dispositivos mobile com hardware na maioria das vezes um pouco fraco.

Answer (score 0):

A solução da ultilização da biblioteca Android.OS provavelmente resolva nos casos onde é utilizado o Xamarin.Droid, mas já que questão levantada é a respeito do Xamarin.Forms para que seja executada uma tarefa em um intervalo determinado é necessario a utilização de Timers, segue o link de um teste para ver o comportamento de um timer em Xamarin.Forms.
[Código teste de timer em Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/acaliaro/TestThread/blob/master/TestThread/TestThread.cs)

Comment: Jorge Carlos Guedert com a Solução Handler está satisfatória, e já vejo como resolvido este post, e através da solução que implantei Handler, estou utilizando além do esperado perfeito, e o melhor sem falhas, e o mais importante o sistema esta funcionando sem sobrecarregar o dispositivo móvel.